# How to make an "if statement" for Rails has_many Association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, conditional-statements

I have the following in my UsersController

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])

  if current_user.id != params[:id] #! need to fix this
    @answer = Answer.new
  else
    @answer = Answer.find(params[:id])
  end
```

where each user has_many answers through a quizzes model. How can I write the if statement so if the answers are blank for that particular user it'll jump to creating a new quiz? (and if they aren't, to display the information).

Comment: Well I'm a bit unclear as to all the details of your set up here - there's no quiz or answer information - but if you want to check if a user has taken a specific quiz why not create a cross join table for users and quizzes and it only gets set up when they take the quiz (or you can make it more complicated than that if you wanted to).  My belief is that your logic of basing it on the answers is wrong and you should instead base it on the quiz?  But I'm making assumptions of things not seen (or presented)

Comment: While many people could take a stab in the dark at this, it may be a little more helpful to provide a bit more information, for example when you say a user has many answers through a quizzes model, are you referring to an actual `has_many :answers, through: :quizzes` relation, or just stating that a user has_many quizzes, and that quizzes has_many answers? perhaps put up your models code as well?

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear what are you trying to achieve as your code is doing unwanted check.SO if you just want to check if any user(**assuming signed_in users**) want to go to show action conditionally,i think you may try this:-

```
##assuming user has_many answers
##answer belongs_to user
def show
  ##get the user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  ##verify if answer is present
  if @user.answers.present?
    @answer = @user.answers
  else
    @answer = @user.answers.new
  end
end
```

*The above logic can be used to has many through associations as well,just need to change to through model*

Hope it helps :)

Comment: please for god's sake don't use unless - else

Comment: @Milind I used this but for some reason, it doesnt allow me to access every other users quizzes, giving me a to_key error, and if it does, answers when submitted do not display in the text fields after.

Comment: try to check your associations...it should work ...play around in console...@user = User.new...then @user.answer.new...it should work ..assuming your answers/quizes table have foreign_key .. :)